# Disable Internet Explorer 11 browser location website redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, internet-explorer

On Windows Server 2012 R2 how do I stop Internet Explorer 11 from redirecting `google.com` to `google.ie` and any other sites as well?

The server happens to be located in Ireland as it is running on AWS, but it's really annoying to be redirected to geo-located sites.

I tried enabling the `Turn off browser location` GPO, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Some website use your ip to locate you & redirect, but for google you can;

> Visit Google.com instead of your local domain
>
> If you want to use google.com instead of your local Google site, you
>   can. To use google.com for searches, you have two options:
>
> •If you've been redirected by google.com to another google site (like
>   google.fr), click the google.com link in the bottom right corner of
>   any other Google page
>
> •Bookmark http://www.google.com/ncr. Anytime you visit this page,
>   you’ll be taken to Google.com.

from https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=en

Comment: Right I've seen that Google link at the bottom of any Google page. I used Google as an example, but as I mentioned it happens with other sites as well. Is there nothing I can do about it?

Comment: With the GPO you enabled, no, as they are using the source ip to locate you :(  It's like to see Advertising for your city, I'am french, and I see english AD that tell my city name.